# How to query nested structure in elasticsearch

Tags: json, elasticsearch, nosql

Below are two mocked records from my elasticsearch index. I have millions of records in my ES. I am trying to query ES to get all the records that have non-empty/ non-null "tags" field. If a record doesn't have a tag ( like second record below) then I don't want to pull it from ES.

If "books" were not nested then googling around seems like the below query would have worked -

```
curl -XGET 'host:port/book_indx/book/_search?' -d '{
    "query" : {"filtered" : {"filter" : {"exists" :{"field" : "_source"}}}}
}'
```

However I am not finding a solution to query the nested structure. I tried the below with no luck -

```
{"query" : {"filtered" : {"filter" : {"exists" :{"field" : "_source.tags"}}}}}

{"query" : {"filtered" : {"filter" : {"exists" :{"field" : "_source":{"tags"}}}}}}
```

Any suggestions are really appreciated here! Thanks in advance.

```
{
"_shards": {
    "failed": 0,
    "successful": 12,
    "total": 12
},
"hits": {
    "hits": [
        {
            "_id": "book1",
            "_index": "book",
            "_source": {
                "book_name": "How to Get Organized",
                "publication_date": "2014-02-24T16:50:39+0000",
                "tags": [
                    {
                        "category": "self help",
                        "topics": [
                            {
                                "name": "time management",
                                "page": 6198
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "calendar",
                                "page": 10
                            }
                        ],
                        "id": "WEONWOIR234LI",
                    }
                ],
                "last_updated": "2015-11-11T16:28:32.308+0000"
            },
            "_type": "book"
        },
        {
            "_id": "book2",
            "_index": "book",
            "_source": {
                "book_name": "How to Cook",
                "publication_date": "2014-02-24T16:50:39+0000",
                "tags": [],
                "last_updated": "2015-11-11T16:28:32.308+0000"
            },
            "_type": "book"
        }
    ],
    "total": 1
},
"timed_out": false,
"took": 80
```

}

Mapping -

```
        "book": {
            "_id": {
                "path": "message_id"
            },
            "properties": {
                "book_name": {
                    "index": "not_analyzed",
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "publication_date": {
                    "format": "date_time||date_time_no_millis",
                    "type": "date"
                },
                "tags": {
                    "properties": {
                        "category": {
                            "index": "not_analyzed",
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "topic": {
                            "properties": {
                                "name": {
                                    "index": "not_analyzed",
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "page": {
                                    "index": "no",
                                    "type": "integer"
                                }                     
                            }
                        },
                        "id": {
                            "index": "not_analyzed",
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    },
                    "type": "nested"
                },
                "last_updated": {
                    "format": "date_time||date_time_no_millis",
                    "type": "date"
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you also share your mapping for the `book` type? Is the `tags` field a `nested` field or a normal `object` field? I'm also surprised to not see the `_source` in your documents.

Comment: @Val thanks for pointing out _source was missing - I accidently renamed it. Made the updates above and included the mapping file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `tags` field has a `nested` type, you need to use a [`nested` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/query-dsl-nested-filter.html) in order to query it.

The following filtered query will correctly return only the first document above (i.e. with id `book1`)

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "tags",
          "filter": {
            "exists": {
              "field": "tags"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. It worked great! (Apologies for the delayed response)